# How to update column with different values per row in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a column in a table I would like to update with values:

`["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

Here is my current code:

`%w{A B C D E F G H I}.each do |l|
     Table.update_all(attribute: l)
end`

This works but it spits out 'I' inside each row, which isn't what I need.

How can I do that in rails 3.2?

Comment: What your code does is to first set the value of all records to A, then all records to B, etc until it at last sets the value of all records to I. Exactly what is it you want to accomplish? Do you really want to update existing records or insert new ones?

Comment: @DanneManne I need to insert new values into newly created attribute for the table, so that "A".."I" are inserted sequentially.

Comment: Okay, but for the attribute (column), do you mean insert new values for existing records (rows) or do you want to create new records (rows) with the specified values for the new attribute?

Comment: I want to inset new record with the specific values for the new attribute...

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you only use the update methods when you want to update existing records in a table. But when you want to insert new rows, then you should use the `create` methods.

Try the following code instead:

```
%w{A B C D E F G H I}.each do |l|
  Table.create(attribute: l)
end
```

If there is any problem with that code, it might be because of some usage of `attr_accessible` or `attr_protected` inside the `Table` model that blocks the assignment of the values.

Edit:

So I don't know the criteria for how you want to update the existing rows but here are a few ways that will give different results, maybe one of them is what you want. Or maybe they will give you some references as to what you can do.

```
# Will update one row for each of the entries in the array but it will only update as many
# rows in the table as there are entries in the array.
%w{A B C D E F G H I}.each_with_index do |l, i|
  t = Table.offset(i).first
  t.update(attribute: l) unless t.nil?
end

# Will go through all the records in the Table and set a value for the new column. If
# there are more records in Table than in the Array, it will start over from the 
# beginning of the Array again.
arr = %w{A B C D E F G H I}
Table.all.each_with_index do |t, i|
  t.update(attribute: arr[i % arr.length])
end
```

Comment: This worked, but it created nils for subset of existing columns. So, here is what it is. I have a table with existing columns and their values. I am adding a new column to it and I need to update that column with values "A, B, C" etc. I am just not sure which Rails method I need to use to do that.

Comment: Hmm, I'm still not sure exactly what you want. What you are saying is a little confusing. First off, columns do not have values, rows have values for each column. But I'm gonna take another guess as to what you want. So you had a table with existing rows. Then you added a new column. And now you want to update the existing rows with different values for this new column. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
values = %w{A B C D E F G H I}
count = 0

Table.find_each do |row|
  row.update_attributes(attribute: values[count % values.length])
  count = count + 1
end
```

Note the use of `find_each`, which allows you to access a large number of records without loading them all into memory at one time, important if your table has many rows.

This approach simply cycles through the provided values, setting them sequentially on each record found: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, A, B, C...

Comment: Thanks. I am getting `wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)` error.

Comment: Whoops! It should have been `update_attributes` instead of `update_attribute`. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found this to work is via finding the record first, then updating the record with the new value, as in the following example:

`Table.find_by_some_other_attribute("Name of the Attr").update_column(:attribute, "A")`

Unfortunately, this has to be done for each letter.